# Google Drive API V3 "Login Required" even when I send auth token in the request

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-oauth

so I'm getting a 401 error even when sending auth token, here's my code

```
var file = document.getElementById('input-file').files[0];
var metadata = {
      'mimeType': file.type,
    'name': name, // Filename at Google Drive
    'parents': ['0AN75N3P23eTJUk9PVA'], // Folder ID at Google Drive
};

var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token; // Here gapi is used for retrieving the access token.
var form = new FormData();
form.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], { type: 'application/json' }));
form.append('supportsAllDrives',true);
form.append('auth',accessToken);
form.append('file', file);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('post', 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onload = () => {
    console.log(xhr.response.id); // Retrieve uploaded file ID.
};
xhr.send(form);
```

Thanks in advance

#### Note:

- The query works when uploading to my drive, however when trying to upload to that shared drive is when the error occurs

Comment: Why dont you use the google api js client library?

Comment: Do you have api key?

Comment: @Nemanja Yes. The query works when uploading to my drive, however when trying to upload to that shared drive is when the error ocurs